# How to get TimeZone, latitude and longitude using single Google API Call

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-timezone

I have address(city,state,country,zip) and want to get TimeZone , latitude and longitude in single Google API call , i see google provide TimeZone api which accepts latitude and longitude and returns TimeZone but that requires two api call , first is to get location ( lat/lng) and second call to get TimeZone from location , not sure if google provide such api which can solve this problem in single call.

Comment: I don't know why -1 given here ?. any reasons what i missed ?.
please let me know so i can improve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can at least get the number of minutes this place's current timezone is offset from UTC together with its coordinates using **[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)**. You can look for the logs 'utc_offset' under 'result' property.

The response includes the following:

> geometry: The place's geometry-related information. This includes:
>   location provides the latitude and longitude of the place.
>   viewport defines the preferred viewport on the map when viewing this place.
>
> utc_offset: contains the number of minutes this place’s current timezone is offset from UTC. For example, for places in Sydney, Australia during daylight saving time this would be 660 (+11 hours from UTC), and for places in California outside of daylight saving time this would be -480 (-8 hours from UTC).

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
I guess you referring to google places api which again required other parameters like place_id , i was thinking google geocoding api could have return timezone or utc_offset along with longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) as @rafon said. But you should use setFields method and add `utc_offset_minutes`.

Like that `autoComplete.setFields(['utc_offset_minutes'])`

You can not get utc_offset_minutes from geocoding api.